# Take my ~/.zshrc when make sudo in CentOS

Tags: centos, zsh

In ubuntu and debian: when I go to root over `sudo -E zsh`
it automaticali load my .zshrc.

In CentOS after sudo I must type `source ~my_user/.zshrc` every time.

How I can load my .zshrc automaticaly in CentOS?

Upd:

I found a solution for myself:

```
sudo -E HOME=$HOME zsh
```

The reason why the `HOME` variable is overwriting is because `/etc/sudoers` contains:

```
Defaults    always_set_home


# Preserving HOME has security implications since many programs
# use it when searching for configuration files. Note that HOME
# is already set when the the env_reset option is enabled, so
# this option is only effective for configurations where either
# env_reset is disabled or HOME is present in the env_keep list.
```

As far as I understand this is done for security reasons.
So that when running programs with elevated privileges, the settings files from my user's home directory could not be used to attack the system.

[sudo man](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html)

[sudoers man](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.20/sudoers.man.html)

Comment: `sudo -E HOME=$HOME zsh`
works.

But why `HOME` variable is overwriting?
`
    sudo --help

        -E, --preserve-env          preserve user environment when running command`

Comment: Maybe the option `env_reset` in `/etc/sudoers` is different between these three systems?!